# django: Can not find the Data table row of the Extra field on many-to-many relationships?

Tags: django, django-models

Hello i am trying to understand Django Data Models and it´s possibilities. After using one-to-one and m2m i am now trying to  understand the m2m extra fields. So i followed the Example of the Django Doc and populated the models with some Data.

> models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

---

So far everything is fine, but as i looked into the model tables, via pgAdmin 4 ( i am using PostgreSQL), i could not find any `members` column in the `Group` model.  So i made a little visual of my model and some screenshots of pgAdmin, for better understanding.

[image]

As you can see `Group` has only a `id` and `name` column.

> Question

my question: Is this m2m `members` relation of `Group`, only some kind of "virtual" created relation via the `Membership.person.fk` and `Membership.group.fk`? Meaning there is no field which will be populated? I try to imagine that it works like a recursive, instance query?

Comment: Yes that's exactly where it is. Although I don't know what you mean by "recursive, instance query"; it's a JOIN.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman "recursive, instance query" yeah maybe misleading :-). So it´s a "virtual" JOIN?